# how do I extract the SubDir name 4 deep & put into a Var 4 later use?

Tags: shell-script, directory-structure

I need to know how to get the 4th directory name into the tree. this directory var changes while working through it using a loop, so while the loop is running always updating this directory structor I need to update this and keep it current

/dir 1/dir 2/dir 3/dir 4/dir 5/
I only need to get that name that is in that 4th dir into a var to use it elsewhere

I am using a loop and extraction like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

working_dir="/media/data/temp1"

script_dir="$HOME/working"

find "$working_dir" -type f -name "*.*" | while [ $xf  -lt $numberToConvert ] ; 
do read FILENAME;

j=$FILENAME
xpath=${j%/*} 
xbase=${j##*/}
xfext=${xbase##*.}
xpref=${xbase%.*}
path1=${xpath}

pref1=${xpref}
ext1=${xfext}
echo 
echo
echo "xpath is -> "$xpath""
echo "xbase is -> "xbase""
echo "xfext is -> "$xfext""
echo "xpref is -> "$xpref""
echo "path is -> "$path1""
echo "pref is -> "$pref1""
echo "ext is -> "$ext1""
echo
getme="$(basename "$working_dir/")" 
echo "GET ME "$getme""
echo

  //Code that does stuff to files in dir's after the 4th Dir
  // is here but hidden 

let xf++
done
```

the output to all of that is:

```
xpath is -> /media/data/temp1/Joe Jackson - The Ultimate Collection/CD2
xbase is -> xbase
xfext is -> mp3
xpref is -> Jumpin' Jive Live - Joe Jackson
path is -> /media/data/temp1/Joe Jackson - The Ultimate Collection/CD2
pref is -> Jumpin' Jive Live - Joe Jackson
ext is -> mp3

GET ME temp1
```

basename returns the 3rd dir not the 4th one after that one, that is what I need to get the name of the one between /temp1/ ... / and CD

```
/media/data/temp1/Joe Jackson - The Ultimate Collection/CD2
```

that Joe Jackson ... dir name will change when the script is done with it going into another 4th dir with a different name so I need to be able to have it update and keep current getting JUST that 4th dir name.

all I need is that line something like this

```
    4thDirNameIs=${code goes here}
```

it is 4 deep into the directory structor not 5 or 3 or any other dir or file name even.

that title tells it all into is the key word one has to be outside of the directoy in oder to go into it 4th directory name into the directories.

I hope that is clear enough this time

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. You give us a lot of unnecessary detail but don't explain what you really need. Why is it the 4th? 4th from where? Where will you be running this from? What is the result you actually want? Is it `Joe Jackson - The Ultimate Collection`? This is the 4th directory down from `/tmp`, is that what you mean? Are you starting from the directories or from the mp3 files? Is this something you will be running for all mp3 files or for all directories? Please rewrite this, explaining what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I clearly stated I needed the 4th directory within that structior more then once, that is what it said the 4th dir down how you figures it out so why you telling me you're confused? that confuses me... I want to get the name of the 4th directory within that directory string like I said, that is all I need to know .. what I do with it or the files  after I get the name of the dir is not part of the question.

Comment: Look, I'm only trying to help you get an answer. Often, when we write, we think that it is clear but it isn't to somebody else. I can't understand what you need. I know you said 4th level but you didn't say 4th level from _what_. You didn't say where you will be running this from which changes everything. As for what you want it for, I know it isn't part of the question but it should be because our answers will depend on that. I think what you are trying to say is that you have directories with the artist name and then want to do something with the files inside. Is that correct?

Comment: you're giving me a complex -- I need the 4th dir name going from left to right making it a subDIr really, therefore it too can be said that I need the 3rd sub directory within a single tree. if I went from right to left then that would not always be the 4th dir down or into the tree. 'into' being the key word here. indecating going into the directoies that'd have to start from the left before entering into the sub directories, not the other way around. my englaish is not that bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file is saved as `$FILENAME`, these will all give you the 4th directory. In these examples, I am manually setting

```
FILENAME="/media/data/temp1/Joe Jackson - The Ultimate Collection/CD2/Jumpin' Jive Live - Joe Jackson.mp3"
```

- Use the shell:

  ```
  $ dir=${FILENAME#*/*/*/*/}; echo ${dir//\/*}
  Joe Jackson - The Ultimate Collection
  ```

  Here, I am first removing the first 4 slashes, leaving the 4th directory and file name and then removing the file name.
- Shell and `basename`:

  ```
  $ dir=${FILENAME#*/*/*/*/}; basename "$dir"
  Jumpin' Jive Live - Joe Jackson.mp3
  ```

  Same idea as above really, just using `basename` for the final step.
- Parse it with Perl:

  $ echo "$FILENAME" | perl -pe 's#(.*?/){4}(.*?)/.*#$2#'
  Joe Jackson - The Ultimate Collection

  The regular expression matches 4 repetitions of 0 or more characters followed by a slash, then everything to the next slash and then everything else. The parentheses let you capture a matched pattern so we are replacing everything with the second pattern mathched, the directory name.

  Alternatively, you can split the line into an array on slasehs and print the 5th field (5th because the 1st is empty due to the `/` at the beginning of the variable):

  ```
  $ echo "$FILENAME" | perl -F"/" -lane 'print $F[4]'
  Joe Jackson - The Ultimate Collection
  ```
- Parse it with `awk`:

  ```
  $ echo "$FILENAME" | awk -F"/" '{print $5}'
  Joe Jackson - The Ultimate Collection
  ```

  Same idea, but in `awk`.

Comment: nope - that is giving me file names and dir they are in, I need that "sudo root dir name. meaning the root dir to the song files name that WILL be the forth 4th dir name into the string just after /media/data /temp1/THIS ONE that it the 4th dir whos name I need - I need the name of that directory is all /

Comment: @uxserx-bw yes, that would be in the `$artist` variable. As I said, your question is not very clear so I'm having trouble understanding what you need.

Comment: it clearly stateed I needed the name off the 4th dir "I need the th dir name going into it"

Comment: @uxserx-bw and isn't that what the `$artist` variable prints?

Comment: nope that didn't work I reworte this wueation on HOW DO I GET the 4th directory name --- DIRECTORY name not files thank you

Comment: @uxserx-bw thanks for the edit, it is clearer now. Try the updated answer. Oh, and DON'T SHOUT AT PEOPLE TRYING TO HELP YOU.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the mindepth and maxdepth arguments for find and pipe that to awk.

`find $someBaseDir -type d -mindepth 4 -maxdepth 4 | awk -F'/' '{ print $NF }'`

If you want to do something for each result, you can put it in a for loop:

Maybe something like:

`for fdir in $(find $Base -type d -mindepth 4 -maxdepth 4 | awk -F'/' '{ print $NF }'); do 
    DO_STUFF_WITH $fdir
done`

Comment: find $goo -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec basename {} \;
works in command line giving me the 4th dir name BUT in a loop it strips only the first name off dir like all of the rest of them  for get_dir (find $goo -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec basename {} \;) echo $get_dir results in one name if multiple names in dir between spaces .. yours throws an error in command line which is stupid because format is same with this one. yours - find: warning: you have specified the -mindepth option after a non-option argument -type, .... error saying mindepth and maxdepth in wrong place after -type d

Answer (score 0):

Jong's answer is really close, but the `mindepth` and `maxdepth` argumentss are relative to the starting directory of the `find` command. You might also consider the fact that you already have the first three parts of the directory structure that you need. Working from that point, you really only need to go **one** level deeper to get the information you are looking for. This has the added benefit of excluding everything else in the directory **except** for the things you want. The following snippet uses your pre-defined variable `$working_dir`, the `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` arguments to `find` and parameter expansion to find every directory at the "4 deep" position in /media/data/temp1:

```
for my_dir in $(find ${working_dir} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print)
    do
    DirName=${my_dir##${working_dir}/}
    ## loop through, working on the 4th directory list
    ## one directory at a time
    . . .
done
```

And FWIW, you shouldn't start variable names with a number. Some shells (like BASH) will interpolate those as references to positional parameters and won't do what you expect (e.g, `$4thDirNameIs` will be expanded to positional parameter `$4`, which may or may not exist, followed by 'thDirNameIs').

Comment: that is ctually I believe to be something I need now in another sctipt  I am adding to it to change the dir name after it is completed with all of the fiiles inside of dir. Problem is if I have to shut down the script before hand it may cause problems if files within it have only been part  done -- for what he gave it it works I get all of the dir fist cycle through them resample mp3 the 4th dir name is taken to strip out all of that extra crap within its name then is created elsewhere for the resampled file to go into. with this different sctipt that leaves the files where they are

Comment: CORRECTION -- that almost works for another project I am working on but the output is messed up - if you echo the var my_dir with input that has spaces in the dir name you only get the first word of that dir ie.  /media/data/test-run/Third eye blind [Discography] the output of my_dir is just Third leaving the rest of the dir name only 4 the next word in that dir to be picked up next time around

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone in this question that helped me this is the answer I came up with, it finds all dir that are the 4th dir in off of root dir/folder then goes into one dir at a time gets all of the files and works on them within the most inner loop. after all selected files are completed it moves onto the next basedir 4th postion and its subdir's then does the same

controled by user input to how many dir he wants to have it work on and where

```
#!/bin/bash

typeset -i f d control DirCountDn fileCount dirCount
let f=0 d=0 control=1  DirCountDn=0 fileCount=0 dirCount=0

amount_of_dir_to_work_on="4"

working_dir="/media/data/music"


   #CONTROL LOOP keeps it one dir at a time
        for i in 1
        do
            # get all of the names of the base dir to change name  a var containing ampunt of basenamedir in last place here 
            find "$working_dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | while [ $DirCountDn  -lt $amount_of_dir_to_work_on ] ; 
                do read DIRNAME;
                    echo "$DIRNAME"
                    echo
                    MAXMP3="$(find "$DIRNAME" -type f -name "*.mp3" | wc -l)"
                    echo;echo;echo
                    echo "amount of mp3 "$MAXMP3" in "$DIRNAME""
                    echo;echo;echo;echo
                        find "$DIRNAME" -type f -name "*.mp3" | while [ $fileCount -lt $MAXMP3 ] ;
                        do read FILENAME;
                            echo;echo
                            echo "***************************************"
                            echo "FILENAME is "$FILENAME""
                            DIRNAME=${DIRNAME#*/*/*/*/} 
                            DIRNAME=${DIRNAME//\/*}
                            echo "DIRNAME is "$DIRNAME""
                            echo
                            echo " work each mp3 file in incurments until Dir is finised will all mp3 files" 
                            echo "rename dir then make provisons to move it somewhere else"
                            echo "then move it - go onto nest directory within the tree root dir"
                            echo "amount of filename "$fileCount""
                            echo "******************************************"
                            let fileCount++
                            echo "count on file names "$fileCount""
                            echo;echo

                        done
                let dirCount++
                echo "Dir Count "$dirCount""
                echo;echo
                let DirCountDn++

                #reset fileCount for next dir
                let fileCount=0
                done

                echo "this is i -> "$i""
        done

 # returns sub dir only one deep and not working dir
#find /dir/dir/dir/getThisOneNameOnly  -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1  -type d   -exec basename {} \;
```